# Angular 5 "ng build" shows no errors "ng build --prod" has many errors

Tags: angular

I know this has been asked before but nothing I read is helping.

after `ng build` there are no errors

after 'ng build --prod'

```
ERROR in src/app/catalog/product/product.component.html(19,43): : Property 'length' does not exist on type 'object'.
src/app/catalog/product/product.component.html(36,39): : Property 'specs' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src/app/catalog/product/product.component.html(58,8): : Property 'config' does not exist on type 'ProductComponent'. Did you mean 'Configs'?
src/app/catalog/product/product.component.html(59,14): : Property 'config' does not exist on type 'ProductComponent'. Did you mean 'Configs'?
src/app/catalog/product/add/add.component.html(14,8): : Property 'pre_configs' does not exist on type 'object'.
src/app/catalog/product/add/add.component.html(30,28): : Property 'sets' does not exist on type 'object'.
src/app/catalog/product/add/add.component.html(70,32): : Property 'price' does not exist on type 'object'.
src/app/catalog/product/add/add.component.html(70,32): : Property 'price' does not exist on type 'object'.
src/app/navigation/mini/mini-search/mini-search.component.html(9,5): : Property 'searchText' does not exist on type 'MiniSearchComponent'.
src/app/navigation/mini/mini-search/mini-search.component.html(13,5): : Property 'searchText' does not exist on type 'MiniSearchComponent'.
src/app/catalog/single/single.component.html(5,24): : Property 'id' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
src/app/catalog/single/single.component.html(74,25): : Property 'id' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
src/app/navigation/maga/maga.component.html(5,8): : Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
```

This is an extremely annoying problem. I started to look at the errors one by one and will continue to but the errors just done make sense and that route will take me several hours. Can anyone advise me on where to start or why there are new errors after `--prod`?

## Update: example of one of the errors

**in my components html**

```
<div *ngIf="sample?.specs">
    <div class="spec-section" *ngFor="let section of sample.specs">
        <h2>{{section.name}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

error after `ng build --prod`

```
ERROR in ../product/product.component.html(37,12): : Property 'specs' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

The following is the component code for getting `sample`

```
constructor(public configsService: ConfigsService) {
    this.sample = configsService.sample_data;
}
```

after `ng serve` or deploying `ng build` the fronend looks/ works fine. The error just pops up durring `ng build --prod`

Comment: Make your properties `public` which you are accessing in the component template (html)

Comment: One thing I've seen before with similar errors is that there are properties or functions that are set as private in the component that you are trying to access from the template. Private properties are only accessible from the class the're declared in. AOT (--prod build) enforces that rule.

Comment: First thing I would do is check your environments.ts file. It may say `production: false`. Try changing that to `true`.

Comment: public did not work

Comment: I think i need someone to look at the errors and let me know if anything sticks out

Comment: @mgm87 / faisal I updated the question to include an example. Can you look?

Comment: Can you post your ts file?

Comment: which one? the service?

Comment: No, the component which includes all those 'missing' properties

Comment: i posted it in the question. it is only the constructor cause it is the only relevant part.

Comment: Well, it is not enough because what's important is the type of your component properties. As the compiler says, your objects or types do not have the properties. That said, NG build prod runs an AOT compilation thus validating everything in compilation time. Read more about it here: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#phase-3-binding-expression-validation

Comment: What's the declared type of  `this.sample`? Try declaring it as `any` if it does not have a type. When using aot, variables using in the template must be declared on the component and  have the right type. You've got several kinds of errors in that error report you showed

Comment: I posted the fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each error had its own fix mostly related to how I was getting data from my service.

## Example 1 of a fix

```
constructor(public configsService: ConfigsService) {
    this.sample = configsService.sample_data;
}
```

Should be..

```
get sample() { return this.configsService.Sample_data; }
constructor(public configsService: ConfigsService) {}
```

For this to work I had to put a get in the service

```
import { Sample } from '../_data/sample_product';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigsService {
    sample_data = Sample;
    constructor()  {}
    get Sample_data() { return this.sample_data; }
}
```

## Example 2 of a fix

**html**

```
<a (click)="config=!config" class="button">Configure</a>
```

that worked in `ng serve` and `ng build` but not in `ng build --prod` because I did not declare `config` in the component. Like this `config:boolean;`

`(answer.helped) ? upvote() : comment();`